# robot in Rviz cannot move and dropping the first 1 trajectory point

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! I'm now following the book *Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming* and build my robot in rviz and gazebo. I wrote the launch file to bring up both rviz and gazebo but some problems appeared. The first one is that after the rviz started, I give the robot a new position and click the plan and execute.it can plan successfully but cannot execute in other words, the robot in rviz cannot move to the goal position. Meanwhile in the terminal there is also a warning `[ WARN] [1509967616.528903811, 3368.707000000]: Dropping first 1 trajectory point(s) out of 13, as they occur before the current time. First valid point will be reached in 0.459s.`  I guess that the warning is asociated with the first problem. I have searched the similar problem but I still cannot slove the problem. Could some one give me some suggestion?
here is the launch file bringup.lunch which launch the rviz and gazebo together.when click the plan and execute,the robot can move correctly in gazebo but do not move in rviz.

```
<launch>

 <!-- Launch Gazebo -->
<include file="$(find jaka_ur_description_pkg)/launch/gazebo.launch" />
<!-- ros_control seven dof arm launch file -->
<include file="$(find jaka_ur_description_pkg)/launch/jaka_ur_gazebo_joint_states.launch" />
<!-- ros_control position control dof arm launch file -->
<!--<include file="$(find jaka_ur_description_pkg)/launch/jaka_ur_gazebo_position.launch" /> -->
<!-- ros_control trajectory control dof arm launch file -->
<include file="$(find jaka_ur_description_pkg)/launch/jaka_ur_trajectory_controller.launch" />
<include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config2)/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch" />
</launch>
```

and the related config file trajectory_control.yaml file

```
 jaka_ur:
  jaka_joint_controller:
    type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6
    gains:
      joint_1:   {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
      joint_2: {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
      joint_3:  {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
      joint_4:       {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
      joint_5:    {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
      joint_6:      {p: 1000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 0.0}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275087/robot-in-rviz-cannot-move-and-dropping-the-first-1-trajectory-point/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-07**:
It's very difficult to debug this problem if you don't show us some code. The error message tells us nothing because we're not familiar with your code. How do you make your robot move? Do you publish some message on topic? Do you have gazebo plugin for simulating this behavior in your model?

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-07**:
sorry. Now i put the launch file and the config fiel I guess that could have some problem.If you think that is not enough I will put others.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-07**:
Can you reformat your launch file? It's very hard to read it this way.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-07**:
Sorry about that.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-12**:
I have found the problem.It was a problem in the package ros-controls/ros_controllers. [joint_trajectory_controller - Always dropping first trajectory point #291](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/issues/291) gave the solution.I tried and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the problem.It was a problem in the package ros-controls/ros_controllers. joint_trajectory_controller - Always dropping first trajectory point #291 gave the solution.I tried and it worked!

---

Originally posted by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) with karma: 88 on 2017-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-13**:
[This](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/issues/291) is the link to the issue for other people.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-13**:
yes, just as what I said above,I trieds it and have solved it.

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2019-01-11**:
i'm also facing same issue, can you please tell me how can i edit the file "ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_msg_utils.h"??

it is located in following path on my pc "/opt/ros/kinetic/include/joint_trajectory_controller"

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2019-01-11**:
and when i try to edit and save the file, i get error as "access is denied".

**Comment by [Yesika Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/52585/yesika-rodriguez/) on 2020-03-16**:
You have need change permission of the file, with sudo chmod 777 nameFile